# What does the embossed text say on the "empty milk bottle" in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I know its a trivial detail, but I'm genuinely curious and struggling to find the answer.

Screenshot from in-game:

[image]

Fandom page's image:

[image]

The [Fandom page](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Empty_milk_bottle_(Fallout_4)) had a better, larger picture, but I still couldn't tell what it said. However, the description of the item says:

> The empty milk bottle is a cylindrical, white glass bottle with the company's logo built in to the bottle's shape.

So I thought, "Great, all I need to do is look at the company's logo. Where do I find the company logo, though? Aha! From the vending machine!"

So I then looked at the [Fandom page](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Milk_vending_machine_(Fallout_4)) for the milk vending machine. However, this was less enlightening than I had hoped. The company named on the vending machine is "Little Cobb Creamery", which, as far as I can tell, doesn't seem to match the embossed text on the bottle.

Alright, so that didn't work. Maybe if I search for Little Cobb Creamery I'll learn something? From the company's [Fandom page](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Little_Cobb_Creamery) I only learned this:

> They owned many milk vending machines across the streets, as well as at least one creamery, which provided milk for the Medford area.

Fortunately, "creamery" was a link to the [Fandom page](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Parsons_Creamery) for Parsons Creamery. However, the page was not terribly informative.

Comparing the text to the name "Parsons Creamery", I thought I was on to something at first: I could see an argument for the letters "P-A-R" (depending on the typeface), but when it came to the supposed "S", the embossment looks a lot more like a "T" to me. So I don't think it says Parsons Creamery, either.

For me, this is where the trail runs cold. **What does the embossed text say?**

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[The other answer has some great imagery of the texture of the bottle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/396331/163757) from the game files.  See that answer for the details.

---

I  found this larger image, originally sourced from [seekpng.com](https://www.seekpng.com/ima/u2q8r5r5t4q8o0u2/).  I've circled the words that I was able to make out:

[image: Milk bottle]

<sub>A higher contrast image can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etf1r.png).</sub>

I'm pretty confident in the following:

- Black Circle: **Fresh**
- Red Circle: **Drive**
- Purple Circle: **In**
- Green Circle: **Dairy**

As for the brown circle, I think it might be either an expiration or packaging date, possibly saying "May 1" and then the rest looks like the letters "LK".  I originally though LK might be Roman numerals for the year part of the date, but "K" doesn't exist in Roman numerals.  Alternatively, I can also see it saying "May Milk", which perhaps is the "company" that produced and packaged the milk, but no Fallout lore I've found has any reference to this name.  [From comments](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/396274/what-does-the-embossed-text-say-on-the-empty-milk-bottle-in-fallout-4/396278?noredirect=1#comment556500_396278), it's been said that it looks like "Hay Milk", which in the dairy industry, would denote that the milk came from cows [primarily fed dry hay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haymilk).  Some [other comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/396274/what-does-the-embossed-text-say-on-the-empty-milk-bottle-in-fallout-4/396278#comment556514_396278) pointed out "Raw Milk" and this seems to be what the text is [(see other answer)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/396331/163757)

From some research, seems drive-in dairies were kind of like convenience stores of the 1940s and 1950s, which would suit the *Fallout* time period/theme (prior to the world being destroyed that is).  One real life example I found was [Rockview Farms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockview_Farms).  Their [history page](https://www.rockviewfarms.com/rockview-history/) even shows pictures of what their drive-in dairies were like.

So, "Fresh Drive In Dairy" makes sense to me to be written on the bottle as a slogan of some sort.  As for the rest of the words, it's way too small/blurry to make out.  The part above the brown circle I can make out a capitalized "A", making me think is could say "Grade A" for [Grade A Milk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grade_A_milk).

Comment: It's LX instead of LK. LX is 60.

Comment: @justhalf I thought it could also be LX, but that would to me denote the year 60 (if it is a date even), and the "end of the world" was in 2077. So unless people had 17 year old milk laying around... I don't think it's LX. Unless the "60" means something totally different.

Comment: This is the world of Fallout, I'm sure that irradiating food products to extend their 'best before' date to *decades* would be a perfectly normal thing :)

Comment: @TimmyJim It's a pretty nice bottle and also empty, maybe the original owner bought milk in 2060, drank it and then kept using the bottle for other things? I still have an empty ramune bottle lying around because its pretty cool

Comment: @Gatchwar certainly possible, but every milk bottle in the game...?  Everyone who bought milk held onto the bottle for 17 years? :) Not saying it's impossible, but its more likely that the developers would have just put LX as an oversight (if it even says LX!)

Comment: It's a glass bottle, so it's unlikely to have an expiration date on it. It looks like ["HAY MILK"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haymilk) to me. Here's [another image with stronger contrast](https://i.imgur.com/zndsHKt.png).

Comment: HAY MILK makes more sense. Haha

Comment: Most likely "RAW MILK", under the red circle, is has a small logo (staring with S), new line with "grade A"

Comment: Honestly, I can see both "RAW" and "HAY".  This is like a [Yanny/Laurel situation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7X_WvGAhMlQ) or the yellow/blue dress.

Comment: Looks very similar to https://imgur.com/VCWBFlp

Comment: Based on the spacing between the letters, and the dent next to what initially looked like a Y, I would say that's a W yeah. And if you zoom in on the first letter it's more likely to be a n R, so RAW MILK it is.

Comment: @TimmyJim Yanny/Laurel or Gold/Blue dress requires that everyone has a strong preference for one in the first impression, and high difficulty in hearing/seeing the other even when pointed out. It's not the case here, I believe, as it's easy to see the other one when pointed out.

Comment: @Linus Great find!  That is a cardboard cap used as a lid for a milk bottle back before foil lids became a thing.

Comment: @TimmyJim I haven't ever done anything with bounties and I read through the Help Center bounties page, but I still don't know what I need to do--if anything--about the bounty on the question.

Comment: @WiZΔRD you don't need to do anything. It's my bounty, thus I have the ability to award it. You can place bounties on your own question, or on others.

Answer (score 15):

The main text says "Fresh Drive-In Dairy".

The middle text says "Raw Milk".

Everything else is small and blurry. The upper bit appears to be a hand-written bit. It might say Parsons Grade A, but I'm not sure. I have no idea what the lower bit says.

[image: Original texture with high-resolution text overlaid showing what I think the text says.]

Object is
*MilkBottleEmpty*

Mesh is
*Props\MilkBottle\MilkBottleempty.nif*

Textures are
*textures\props\milkbottle\MilkBottle_d.dds*
*textures\props\milkbottle\MilkBottle_n.dds*

There are also full and pre-war versions.

[image: Snipped bits of the relevant textures.]

Here's a version I dramatically increased the contrast on that might or might not help at all.

[image: High contrast versions of the snipped textures.]

Comment: What do the different colors denote?

Comment: @TimmyJim They represent different components of the same image for [texture mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping). Images that end with `_d` are "diffuse" (the actual colour), `_n` are ["normals"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping) (fake shadows) and `_s` are ["specular"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_reflection) (reflectivity). The colours for textures other than diffuse are never shown directly on screen, their RGB values are used as data instead. For the normals, the RGB values are X, Y and Z coordinates.

Comment: The hand-written part could just be "Parsons" (which is a company related to the milk vending machine, as OP figured out) and "Grade A", as written by @TimmyJim

Comment: @pinckerman: I had thought about that, but it didn't initially look that way to me. But the right-hand images do make the large "A" pretty clear. And the left side of the script work looks a lot like a slanted "P". I'm still not 100% convinced there are enough letters there, but it could be "Parsons". I added a picture up top with the general consensus stenciled on top of the normal map.